# Deploy contract from external address

Tags: contract-deployment

All the contract deployment tutorials I have seen instruct me to deploy the via my `eth.accounts[0]` or some other address belonging to my nodes account list.
The code in the last step generally is (don't mind the improper syntax)

```
var test = testcontract.new("teststring",{ from: eth.accounts[0], data: "0x" + testOutput.contracts.bin, gas: 300000}});
```

I wish to use an external address in the from field, whose private key I have generated separately without any involvment with the in node wallet.
I cannot find any material which helps me with. How can I do that?

Comment: did you find any solution for the same? Could you please help me in case you found the solution